# Plot of Ramanujan tau function

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms

There is a picture on wikipedia of Ramanujan tau function. At first I noticed that there are exceptional red point (where the red points are sparse in the lower part), this should be due to Sato-Tate conjecture. 
But it seems strange since where red points are dense blue points  are sparse!
Is there any explanation about these?

(Wiki: The blue line picks only the values of n that are multiples of 121.)
[image]

By the way, is there any conjecture about the growth （a lower bound） of this function? (Surely stronger than the Lehmer's conjecture.)

Comment: The probabilistic distribution and growth of $\tau$ is now understood because the Sato-Tate conjecture is proved.

Comment: You can find some explanation on http://www2.math.ou.edu/~rschmidt/satotate/.

Comment: Is S-T proved for modular forms? SO what's the S-T group of $\Delta$? How to explain these sparse points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best lower bound known seems to be due to Ram Murty:

$$\tau(n)=\Omega (n^{11/2}e^{c \log n / \log \log n})$$

for some $c>0$ absolute and effective (note: thanks to the Sato-Tate conjecture might be able to take $c<\log 2$).

This result is proved in:

- Ram Murty, Some Omega results for Ramanujan's tau function (1982)

In their book on Ramanujan, Ram and Kummar mention:

> This result is essentially best possible since we know that
>
> $$d(n)<e^{c' \log n / \log \log n}$$

It might be worth mention that this holds for arbitrary cusp forms, for some $c>0$,

$$a(n)=\Omega (n^{(k-1)/2}e^{c \log n / \log \log n})$$

The exceptional values you observe seem to be related to congruences modulo $11$ and $121$, but I have no idea about that. Ramanujan himself certainly had much to say on the matter:

- Srinivasa Ramanujan, [Properties of $p(n)$ and $\tau (n)$...](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~berndt/articles/pt.pdf) (unpublished)

Hopefully someone can answer that part of your question better.

Comment: The first bound is definitely not proven, since we do not even know that $\tau(n)=0$ only has finitely many solutions. Perhaps you meant it as an upper bound. Then, the Ramanujan conjecture (not Sato-Tate) implies that any $c>\log 2$ is admissible, but this is not due to Murty but Deligne and Ramanujan himself (Deligne proved the Ramanujan conjecture, and Ramanujan determined the order of the divisor function).

Comment: Similarly, the fourth bound would imply the first bound, so that one is unproven as well. There is some big confusion here...

Comment: @GHfromMO You are right, I see my mistake now. The result only holds infinitely often, much like Hardy's proof that $\tau (n) > n^{11/2}$.

Comment: (It's fixed now)

Comment: I had posted the same thing and then deleted it out of serious confusion. If you look at the Murty paper the theorem is stated as |\tau(n)| > \Omega(...). But the meaning of \Omega is never stated! What a perfect example of needing to define all notation! (I could be remembering wrong, of course --- I'm unfortunately only on my phone at the moment.)

Comment: Thank all of you a lot! It seems there are lots of material to check.

Comment: @alpoge: The $\Omega$ notation is standard, but (unfortunately) it means a different thing in analytic number theory than in computer science (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Big_Omega_notation).

Comment: Would you have a reference for the result about arbitrary cusp forms? Thank you,